# How to debug into CUDA kernel code using visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cuda

Hey,
I am using Visual Studio 2008, with CUDA 3.2. I am trying to debug into a function with this signature:

```
 MatrixMultiplication_Kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(Md, Nd, Pd, Width);
```

I can step into the function, however when I get into the function it doesn't let me step over any of the code and tells me that no source is available. Anybody knows how to debug into this properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Update:*** Parallel Nsight is now free and supports debugging with only one GPU in your system.

To debug device code within Visual Studio you will need [Parallel Nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/parallel-nsight.html). The standard version is **free** and offers the debugging you require as well as device code profiling.

If you want to debug on a single machine then you will need two GPUs (since the GPU running the code will be stopped when it hits a breakpoint, and hence your display would block as well). They don't need to be high-end GPUs though, anything from G92 onwards will do (including most Fermi GPUs as listed [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight-requirements.html)).

Comment: Is that true for CUDA-GDB as well?

Answer (score 12):

You can now debug on a single machine with only one GPU using [NSight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html).

Thought I'd update this, since the previous answers are no longer correct (you no longer need 2 GPUs) and it sent me off in the wrong direction for a while.

Comment: You can debug it on one GPU only if you don't use X or have SM3.5, [source](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html#single-gpu-debugging-with-desktop-manager-running)

Comment: I have two Tesla C1060 cards. I am building a GPU machine for my lab and Ill be running it on Linux. So as per your comment, I need to have an extra graphics card (probably on board) running the display/X-server if I want to use CUDA-gdb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [Nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html)?  Vanilla Visual Studio cannot step into device code, but with Nsight, this is possible.  Unfortunately, limitations of the Windows device driver model mean there are some serious restrictions.  It used to be that two machines were required to do the debugging.  The target machine would run the CUDA code on it's GPU, and had to be using the TCC driver.  The host machine would run Visual Studio and control the target.  It seems that it is now possible to debug CUDA code on the same machine as long as you have two GPU's, one for compute and one for display.  There are a number of other problems mentioned in the [user guide](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/ParallelNsight/UserGuide/HTML/User%20Guide.1033_en_US/webframe.html).

This may not be an acceptable answer, but: If you can compile your code on Linux, you can use cuda-gdb to debug kernels.  cuda-gdb is part of the Linux CUDA toolkit.

Comment: "t is now possible to debug CUDA code on the same machine as long as you have two GPU's, one for compute and one for display." Exactly. And both have to be either G92 or GT200. (So, for example, Fermi 470/480's are out.) What percentage of CUDA users does that describe?

Comment: Unfortunately the technical limitations and the fact that CUDA hasn't really been around that long means that only those who have deep pockets can do this kind of debugging.  The rest have to take other approaches.

Comment: See this list for supported GPUs: http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight-requirements.html. Fermi 470/480 is supported in the 1.5 release. It's true that you need two GPUs (otherwise you'd block your display on a breakpoint) but they don't need to be high-end, cost of entry is fairly low!

Answer (score -4):

You can't debug CUDA kernel code using visual studio. Visual studio can only debug programs that run on the CPU.

In fact, I don't think that you can debug CUDA kernel code in Windows at all any more. CUDA used to have a host emulation mode, but that was removed in 3.0. The only debugging tools available are cuda-gdb and ocelot, and, as far as I know, neither of them supports Windows.

Comment: This is incorrect.  NVIDIA Parallel Nsight can be used for on device debugging.