# Do we need two GPUs to debug CUDA code?

Tags: debugging, cuda, gpu

Quoting a comment from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060028/113124):

> If you want to debug on a single machine then you will need two GPUs
>   (since the GPU running the code will be stopped when it hits a
>   breakpoint, and hence your display would block as well).

Although it makes a little sense, don't GPUs have parallelism? I think they do, and if so, I don't see a reason for the display process to be stopped while debugging.

What am I missing?

Comment: There are many kinds of parallelism, and this isn't the kind of parallelism you're looking for.

Comment: @PaulR: Could you please explain a bit regarding what parallelism I am looking for?

Comment: You're looking for either multi CPU/core level parallelism, or possibly even just multi-tasking via time slicing, but either way the CUDA GPU architecture does not provide this - it just executes lots of identical instruction threads in parallel (SIMT).

Comment: The referenced answer is out of date as @Greg Smith points out. I've added a note to that effect on the original. Greg's comment on his answer explains the reason well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nsight Visual Studio Edition 2.2 supports single GPU single system debugging.

cuda-gdb and Nsight Eclipse Edition require you to disable the display if you want to do single GPU debugging.

Comment: Thanks, but why is a display disable needed for `cuda-gdb` and Nsight Eclipse?

Comment: How would yous interact with a debugger if you don't have a display ?

Comment: NV GPUs can only run one context at a time. The current GPUs do not support instruction level pre-emption. When the debugger stops the GPU is really stops the GPU. The state remains on the GPU and can be inspected by the debugger. When this is happening there is no way to context the GPU so that the desktop can be rendered. The Nsight VSE debugger implements a form of instruction level pre-emption for CUDA kernels solely for debugging at the cost of some performance and system resources.

Comment: To @PaulR: to interact with the debugger on a single-GPU machine you would need to debug remotely.

Comment: @Lazer The problem is that most modern desktop environments on Linux (and Quartz on Mac) use hardware acceleration to draw the UI. Thus the system will hang when window environment does an OpenGL call (e.g. to draw a fancy minimize window animation) whilst GPU is suspended by cuda-gdb. Thus you may use cuda-gdb on a single-gpu system if you run it without desktop environment. Nsight EE cannot be ran without desktop environment and thus requires a multi-GPU setup. Note that Optimusa setups qualify as a valid multi-GPU setups.

Comment: @Eugene: you could run Nsight EE remotely with X forwarding if needed.